# Apple Pay - onvalidatemerchant Payment Not Completed error

Tags: ios, applepay, applepayjs

I am implementing apple pay onto our website. I do not have a macOS device and am using windows visual studios / mvcnet. I have done all the merchantID and certification stuff and configured it on the windows machine. I am using Apple Pay JS and on the step where the payment sheet is opened with session.begin(). I use an ajax call to retrieve a merchantSession, which I believe it does successfully because the object consumed by session.completeMerchantValidation(merchantSession) contains an epochnumber, expiration time and the site name. However, immediately after completeMerchantValidation, the oncancel event is fired, and I get a red alert saying "Payment not completed".

I need help with how to proceed from here, I read somewhere online that the domain on where I am testing needs to be a registered merchant domain. For example, when I test the functionality of the button, I need to be on www.mySite.com, where I have mySite.com registered as a domain. Can someone confirm if this is true.. because I am accessing the site from my iOS devices through local IP address. If that is not true, any help proceeding from where I am would be helpful.

```
function StartPaySession() {
    var lineItems = [
        {
            label: 'Shipping',
            amount: '0.00',
        }
    ];

    var shippingMethods = [
        {
            label: 'Free Shipping',
            amount: '0.00',
            identifier: 'free',
            detail: 'Delivers in five business days',
        },
        {
            label: 'Express Shipping',
            amount: '5.00',
            identifier: 'express',
            detail: 'Delivers in two business days',
        }
    ];

    var total = {
        label: 'Apple Pay Example',
        amount: '8.99',
    };

    var paymentData = {
        countryCode: 'US',
        currencyCode: 'USD',
        shippingMethods: shippingMethods,
        lineItems: lineItems,
        total: total,
        supportedNetworks: ['amex', 'discover', 'masterCard', 'visa'],
        merchantCapabilities: ['supports3DS'],
        requiredShippingContactFields: ['postalAddress', 'email'],
    };


    var paySession = new ApplePaySession(2, paymentData);

    paySession.onvalidatemerchant = function (event) {
        var validationData = { ValidationUrl: event.validationURL };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/orders/cart/startapplepaysession',
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(validationData)
        }).then(function (merchantSession) {
            paySession.completeMerchantValidation(merchantSession);
            alert("end = " + window.location.host);
        }, function (error) {
            alert("merchant validation unsuccessful: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            paySession.abort();
        });
    };

    paySession.onpaymentmethodselected = function (event) {
        alert("1");
        paySession.completePaymentMethodSelection(total, lineItems);
    };

    paySession.onshippingcontactselected = function (event) {
        alert("2");
        paySession.completeShippingContactSelection(ApplePaySession.STATUS_SUCCESS, shippingMethods, total, lineItems);
    };

    paySession.onshippingmethodselected = function (event) {
        alert("3");
        paySession.completeShippingMethodSelection(ApplePaySession.STATUS_SUCCESS, total, lineItems);
    }

    paySession.onpaymentauthorized = function (event) {
        var token = event.payment.token;
        alert("payment authorization | token = " + token);
        paySession.completePayment(ApplePaySession.STATUS_SUCCESS);
    }

    paySession.oncancel = function (event) {
        alert("payment cancel error " + event);
    }

    paySession.begin();
};
```

Comment: did u got solution?

Comment: regarding setting up server this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/setting_up_your_server might be helpful.

Comment: @Srigar Yes. No way to test apple pay locally. Have to have to use the same domain as the one registered on your apple developer account.

Comment: what is the code here /orders/cart/startapplepaysession ?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the **Apple pay session** at the wrong place.You **need to create it from server side not on the** **client side**.

These links might help [requesting apple pay payment session](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api/requesting_an_apple_pay_payment_session),  [complete merchant validation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778015-completemerchantvalidation)

Steps are discussed here:[on validate merchant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778021-onvalidatemerchant)

Comment: Perhaps the OP's code was different than it is now, but your answer is misleading.  Using Apple Pay JS you create the session on the client side but perform the merchant validation on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but thought I'd post my experience in case it's relevant.  I was seeing the same behavior as described by original poster when testing on my local server, but was able to get payment sheet interactions to work.

**What worked for me**

1. Log in to AppleID as a [Sandbox Test User](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing)
2. Specify "localhost" as the domain when performing merchant validation, e.g.:

   ```
   {
     "merchantIdentifier": "<your merchant ID>",
     "displayName": "<your merchant display name>",
     "initiative": "web",
     "initiativeContext": "localhost"
   }
   ```